# Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration in wordpress social plugin

Tags: facebook, wordpress

Error - **Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.**

I have created a app for facebook but this error comes in wordpress socil login plugin . If any body know then help me out

Comment: Have you correctly configured your FB app?? check one more

Answer (score 1):

Just add Your Wordpress web page URL to your application settings.
You must add the URL in "Website with Facebook Login" part.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please checkout this

You need to fill the value for Website with Facebook Login with the value `http://localhost/OfferDrive/` to allow Facebook to authenticate that the requests from JavaScript SDK are coming from right place

thank you